# Order by in Unnest

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Explain my Problem with Sample Query

```
select p1.zonename,p1.beatname,p1.groupname,p2.partyname,p2.amount,
p2.groupofcompany from 
party1 p1 inner join party2 p2 on p1.txno=p2.txno
```

This Query show result like this

```
ZoneName BeatName GroupName PartyName Amount Groupofcompany
 AA        BB         CC       A        100        Y
 AA        BB         CC       B        200        Y
 DD        EE         FF       C        300        N
```

But i want display like this

```
  AA          --> Zone Name
  BB          --> Beat Name
  CC          --> Group Name (if groupofcompany y then only show other wise not)
  A      100  --> Party Name And Amount
  B      200
  DD
  EE     
  C      300
```

So, I tried Like this

```
SELECT unnest(array[zonename,beatname,groupname,partyname]) AS partyname,
       unnest(array[0,0,0,amount]) AS Amount,
       unnest(array[1,2,3,4]) AS
ORDER,
       row_number() over()
FROM
  (SELECT p1.zonename,
          p1.beatname,
          CASE
              WHEN p2.groupofcompany='N' THEN ''
              ELSE p1.groupname
          END AS groupname,
          p2.partyname,
          p2.amount,
   FROM party1 p1
   INNER JOIN party2 p2 ON p1.txno=p2.txno) AS tt
ORDER BY row_number() over(),ORDER
```

Its Show Output like this

```
 Party Name Amount Order Row_number

      AA             1      1
      BB             2      1
      CC             3      1
      A      100     4      1
      AA             1      2
      BB             2      2
      CC             3      2
      B      200     4      2
      DD             1      3
      EE             2      3
                     3      3
      C      300     4      3
```

But i want to get like this

```
Party Name Amount

      AA            
      BB            
      CC            
      A      100    
      B      200     
      DD             
      EE            
      C      300
```

How to remove duplicate and correct order (zonename,beatname,groupname,partyname)

Am using **Postgresql 9.3**

Comment: can you provide DDL and Sample Data ??

Comment: Beware of using unnest in select lists: http://www.mesoconcepts.com/2013/06/inconsistent-unnesting-in-postgresql/

Comment: Can you upgrade to 9.4? It supports unnest `with ordinality`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but try like this

```
with cte as (
             select unnest(array[zonename,beatname,groupname,partyname]) as partyname,
                    unnest(array[0,0,0,amount]) as Amount
             from (
                   select p1.zonename,p1.beatname,case when p2.groupofcompany='N' then '' else 
                          p1.groupname end as groupname,p2.partyname, p2.amount
                   from   party1 p1 inner join party2 p2 on p1.txno=p2.txno
                  ) t
            )
select   * from cte 
group by partyname,Amount 
order by (case when partyname = 'AA' then 1
               when partyname = 'BB' then 2
               when partyname = 'CC' then 3
               when partyname = 'A'  then 4
               when partyname = 'B'  then 5
               when partyname = 'DD' then 6
               when partyname = 'EE' then 7
               when partyname = 'C'  then 8
        end)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for valuable time. but order is not correct sir

Comment: Thanks sir. I explain problem with sample data. This is not my real data. I am already mention in question sir.